# Transpose a query output

Tags: sql, oracle11g, transpose

I have a normal select query which results following output.

```
select cid,x1,x2,x3,x4,fy
  from temp_table;

cid     x1  x2  x3  x4  fy
----------------------------
6657    100 0   0   200 2014
6658    300 0   0   400 2015
6659    500 0   0   600 2016
```

I want it to rewrite it print following output.

```
    2014    2015    2016    
-------------------------   
x1  100     300     500     
x2  0       0       0       
x3  0       0       0       
x4  200     400     600
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do this with just subqueries and aggregation:

```
select name,
       sum(case when fy = 2014 then x end) as "2014",
       sum(case when fy = 2015 then x end) as "2015",
       sum(case when fy = 2016 then x end) as "2016"
from (select fy,
             (case when n.n = 1 then 'x1'
                   when n.n = 2 then 'x2'
                   when n.n = 3 then 'x3'
                   when n.n = 4 then 'x4'
              end) as name,
             (case when n.n = 1 then x1
                   when n.n = 2 then x2
                   when n.n = 3 then x3
                   when n.n = 4 then x4
              end) as x
      from temp_table cross join
            (select 1 as n from dual union all
             select 2 from dual union all
             select 3 from dual union all
             select 4 from dual
            ) n
     ) t
group by name;
```

You can also use `pivot`, but that is a very recent addition to Oracle SQL, so I'm inclined to use this method.

Comment: any idea how to do it with `pivot` i am using oracle 11g. There may be a case that we have n number of years in our query output hence the transposed query should have n+1 columns

Answer (score 0):

More general solution is with [UNPIVOT and PIVOT](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506).
Your `temp_table` is already  a pivot table with *(x1  x2  x3  x4)* as **x-axis** and *fy* as **y-axis**.
First we need to UNPIVOT `temp_table` into `unpivoted_temp_table` and then PIVOT it with *fy* as x-axis and *(x1  x2  x3  x4)* as y-axis:

```
with unpivoted_temp_table as (

SELECT *
  FROM   temp_table
  UNPIVOT (
          totalSales                            
          FOR x                             
          IN  (x1, x2, x3, x4)
         )
)  

select *  
FROM   unpivoted_temp_table 
  PIVOT (
               SUM(totalSales)        
           FOR fy          
          IN (2014, 2015, 2016)
         )
order by 1 --order by column X
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4fdfc/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Three possible options to transpose in Oracle 11G

- DECODE Option

  - a. Use SUM and DECODE for the new columns if you want to transpose
    and summarize
  - b. Use MAX and DECODE for the new columns if you want to transpose
    and not to summarize
- Use PIVOT
- Use WITH and SUB SELECT as said by Gordon

To use pivot, it is not possible in your code since your initial data set is already pivoted.

```
WITH TEMP1
    AS (SELECT
             6657 AS CID,
             100 AS VAL,
             'X1' AS XCORD,
             2014 AS FY
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             6657 AS CID,
             0 AS VAL,
             'X2' AS XCORD,
             2014 AS FY
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             6657 AS CID,
             0 AS VAL,
             'X3' AS XCORD,
             2014 AS FY
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             6657 AS CID,
             200 AS VAL,
             'X4' AS XCORD,
             2014 AS FY
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             6658 AS CID,
             300 AS VAL,
             'X1' AS XCORD,
             2015 AS FY
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             6658 AS CID,
             0 AS VAL,
             'X2' AS XCORD,
             2015 AS FY
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             6658 AS CID,
             0 AS VAL,
             'X3' AS XCORD,
             2015 AS FY
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             6658 AS CID,
             400 AS VAL,
             'X4' AS XCORD,
             2015 AS FY
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             6659 AS CID,
             500 AS VAL,
             'X1' AS XCORD,
             2016 AS FY
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             6659 AS CID,
             0 AS VAL,
             'X2' AS XCORD,
             2016 AS FY
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             6659 AS CID,
             0 AS VAL,
             'X3' AS XCORD,
             2016 AS FY
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             6659 AS CID,
             600 AS VAL,
             'X4' AS XCORD,
             2016 AS FY
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      *
FROM
      (SELECT
            XCORD,
            FY,
            SUM ( VAL ) AS VAL
       FROM
            TEMP1
       GROUP BY
            XCORD,
            FY) PIVOT (SUM ( VAL ) FOR FY IN ('2014', '2015', '2016'))
ORDER BY
      XCORD;
```

Results:

```
XCORD   '2014'  '2015'  '2016'
-----   ------  ------  ------
X1  100 300 500
X2  0   0   0
X3  0   0   0
X4  200 400 600
```

If you look into the data set you can see that the results are

```
CID     VAL     XCORD   FY
----    ----    -----   ----
6657    100 X1  2014
6657    0   X2  2014
6657    0   X3  2014
6657    200 X4  2014
6658    300 X1  2015
6658    0   X2  2015
6658    0   X3  2015
6658    400 X4  2015
6659    500 X1  2016
6659    0   X2  2016
6659    0   X3  2016
6659    600 X4  2016
```

Which is more or less a UNPIVOT of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with combination of unpivot and pivot.

```
select * from 
    (select * from 
    (select x1,x2,x3,x4,fy from table1) 
    unpivot(val for x in (x1,x2,x3,x4)))
pivot(sum(val) for fy in (2014,2015,2016))
```