# oracle Same rows Multiple columns group by

Tags: sql, oracle

Could you please help me in resolving this SQL query?

I have two tables as below

TABLE A

```
ID      NUM 
------------
AA      123 
BB      234 
CC      345 
DD      567 
EE      678 
FF      789 
GG      890
```

TABLE B

```
ID      SER 
----------- 
AA      MNP 
BB      MNP 
CC      MN  
DD      PQR 
EE      PQR 
FF      XYZ 
GG      XYZ
```

I want results  to be displayed as below

TABLE C

```
SER        NUM     NUM2 
-----------------------
MNP        123     234  
MN         345     NULL 
PQR        123     234  
XYZ        123     234
```

I have tried different queries. However, not able to get a clue how to get the same column results .

Any Help will be appreciated .

Comment: This is very basic SQL knowledge.

Comment: You said you "have tried different queries." Which?

Comment: @Juergen : I understand it is Basic SQL however not getting a clue how to resolve this.

Comment: @colin : I tried grouping by in inner query and i didn't get the desired result.

Comment: Are you sure the expected results in TABLE C are correct?

Comment: Apart from the last XYZ        123     234   other should be correct

Comment: Also PQR is wrong I guess. Please dont come up with your homework. You dont even know how to write a question!! :(

Comment: Apologies  i Understand i didn't frame the question right however that was more unintended .

Comment: Please edit TABLE C to show the exact results you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
select ser, 
       max(decode(rank, 1, num, null)) num, 
       max(decode(rank, 2, num, null)) num2
from (
  select SER, num, rank() over(partition by SER order by num) rank
  from tablea a 
  inner join tableb b on a.id = b.id
  order by ser, rank() over(partition by SER order by num)
)  
group by ser
```

Here the [demo in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/65b49/6)

Answer (score 0):

[Read this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_converting_rows_columns.htm)

Try this:

```
WITH TABLEA
    AS (SELECT
             'AA' AS ID,
             123 AS NUM
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'BB' AS ID,
             234 AS NUM
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'CC' AS ID,
             345 AS NUM
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'DD' AS ID,
             567 AS NUM
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'EE' AS ID,
             678 AS NUM
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'FF' AS ID,
             789 AS NUM
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'GG' AS ID,
             890 AS NUM
        FROM
             DUAL),
    TABLEB
    AS (SELECT
             'AA' AS ID,
             'MNP' AS SER
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'BB' AS ID,
             'MNP' AS SER
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'CC' AS ID,
             'MN' AS SER
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'DD' AS ID,
             'PQR' AS SER
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'EE' AS ID,
             'PQR' AS SER
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'FF' AS ID,
             'XYZ' AS SER
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'GG' AS ID,
             'XYZ' AS SER
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      TABLEB.SER,
      RTRIM ( XMLAGG ( XMLELEMENT ( E,
                              TABLEA.NUM
                              || ',' ) ).EXTRACT ( '//text()' ),
            ',' )
          NUM
FROM
      TABLEA,
      TABLEB
WHERE
      TABLEA.ID = TABLEB.ID
GROUP BY
      TABLEB.SER
ORDER BY
      TABLEB.SER;
```

Comment: Thank you .However the Query  might work good for a smaller table. How should it be progressed with larger table .  Many Thanks

Comment: Yes.It was very Helpful apart from one constraint it merges all rows into one column.However if you see my above question i wanted it to be different columns

Answer (score 0):

A quick one, if I got what you intend to do:

```
select Y.SER, max(Y.NUM) NUM, max(Y.NUM2) NUM2
from
(
  select B.SER, decode(X.lvl, 1, X.NUM, null) NUM, decode(X.lvl, 2, X.NUM, null) NUM2
  from
  (
    select B.SER, B.ID, A.NUM, rank() over (partition by B.SER order by A.ID) lvl
    from B, A
    where A.ID (+) = B.ID
  ) X, B
  where B.SER = X.SER
    and B.ID = X.ID
) Y
group by Y.SER
;
```

This gives:

```
MNP 123 234
MN  345 
PQR 567 678
XYZ 789 890
```

Depending on the version of Oracle you're using, you could use the [pivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) clause to save one sub-query (but its use is a bit complex).

Answer (score 0):

Intentionally adding another answer: [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826307/transpose-a-query-output/18828985#18828985)

Three possible options to transpose in Oracle 11G

1. DECODE Option

a. Use SUM and DECODE for the new columns if you want to transpose and summarize

b. Use MAX and DECODE for the new columns if you want to transpose and not to summarize

2. Use PIVOT
3. Use WITH and SUB SELECT as said by Gordon

To use pivot, it is not possible in your code since your initial data set is already pivoted.